# angular: how to update value when range input modified via code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to angularJS,

I have a range input, which might get it's value updated via code. I have created a `ng-model` for this input, and have `ng-bind`ed it to a `<p>` tag.

It works fine as long as the range input is modified by the user, but when it is updated by the code, the updated value is not getting reflected.

I have a created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cj1emb1r/16/

How can I make it work?

```
<div ng-app=''>
    <input type='range' min='20' max='200' ng-model="amount" id='slider'>
    <p ng-bind="amount"> </p>
    <button onclick='foo();'> Run!</button>
</div>
```

The function where the value is modified:

```
<script>
    var flag = true;
    function foo() {
        var sliderObj = document.getElementById('slider');
        var value = parseInt(sliderObj.value);
        if(value >= 200 || value <= 0) {
            flag = !flag;
        }
        if(flag) {
            sliderObj.value = value + 5;
        }
        else {
            sliderObj.value = value - 5;
        }
        console.log(value);
        setTimeout("foo()", 200);
    }
</script>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For starters**, I suggest you to read some articles in official [developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide) documentation. And walk through [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), which is very useful for understanding Angular basics.

**Back to your code**, there are couple of fundamental things that you didn't get about Angular.js workflow. In order to control your model you should to use [`controllers`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller). The `amount` variable that you're using as a model in slider ( via `ng-model`) is kept in [`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) or in your case in [`$rootScope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope), I suppose (because there are no any `controllers` or [`directives`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)/[`components`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) in your app). So, if you want to change `amount` value manually, you have to actually change `$rootScope.amount` value. But without `controller` and [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), that attached to it, you simply can't reach `$rootScope` variable.

So, first of all you better define your app [`module`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) and then attach controller to it, so you can manage it's `$scope`.

Here is my [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/bdGtblNl61lcSsPwqE4H?p=preview), how to do that (with comments).

But if to speak, it is recommended by [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) to keep variables not in `$scope` but in `controller` itself. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bdGtblNl61lcSsPwqE4H?p=preview) is how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In your `script`, add -

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
```

after the inner `if-else` loop, add `p.innerHTML=sliderObj.value;`
Angularjs bindings can only be accessed inside angularjs `controllers`. Plain JavaScript doesn't recognize angularjs bindings. Hence, it doesn't change the value of `p` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand , you can call to foo

```
foo();
```

and by default set value

```
value = 155;
```

before you call foo function